# How can I create an MPlayer playlist with a shell script?

Tags: linux, mplayer

I am trying to create a shell script in Linux that when executed searches a directory for all media files then creates a playlist and plays it with MPlayer.

Comment: When faced with a task like this, typically you will want to break it down into steps. Which part have you done so far? (1) Search a directory for all files. (2) Select the media files from a list of files. (3) Create a playlist file from the list of media files. (4) Start mplayer with the given playlist.

Comment: i Search the directory for the files

Comment: not sure how to create the playlist n start mplayer

Comment: OK I FIGURED IT OUT THANKS ANYWAYS

Answer (score 15):

Use this command :

```
find /PATH/TO/MUSIC/DIRECTORY/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" > playlist.m3u
```

Now play with mplayer :

```
mplayer -playlist playlist.m3u
```

Comment: add "sort" to the find, otherwise it won't add the playlist in the right order: find /PATH/TO/MUSIC/DIRECTORY/ -type f -iname "*.mp3" | sort > playlist.m3u